# microsoft.ui.xaml not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I installed the microsoft.ui.xaml NuGeT to my WPF Project and added the following to the app.xaml Merged Dictionarys (as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started) said ):

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>

                <!-- MahApps -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                ...
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But VS displays the following errors:
"CS0234 7   The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
"
and
"
XDG0008 16  The name "XamlControlsResources" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"."

Does someone know how I can make it work / find the assembly error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using WinUI 2.x which is [not compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/) with WPF, it can only be used with UWP.

> The WinUI 2.x Library is closely coupled to the Windows 10 SDK and provides official native Windows UI controls and other UI elements for **UWP apps**.

Support for WPF is introduced in WinUI 3, which is currently only available as [preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/).

Comment: ah, i did not see that. Thank you!